# "Invalid Class String" Dynamically Adding Listview to Multipage

Tags: vba, listview, controls

Unable to dynamically add a listview to a multipage, yet I was able to do so with a list box.

Here's the code I am trying to use...

Does Not Work:

```
Dim lbMyListView As MSComctlLib.ListView
Set lbMyListView = UFHistoricalDataOutput.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.ListView.1", "MyListView", 1)
```

Does Not Work:

```
Dim lbMyListView
Set lbMyListView = UFHistoricalDataOutput.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.ListView.1", "MyListView", 1)
```

Does Not Work:

```
Dim lbMyListView
Set lbMyListView = UFHistoricalDataOutput.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Add("ListView.1", "MyListView", 1)
```

ETC...

Any direction would by appreciated.  TY

Comment: Using a 64-bit VBE host I guess? MSComctlLib only works in 32-bit hosts AFAIK.

Comment: A `ListBox` control should be usable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I am able to paint the ListView control via the VBA editor.  Also, I did use a ListBox previously.  The issue is that with large amounts of data it simply repaints with every scroll event and you have wait for the control to repopulate.

Comment: If it's in the VBE's toolbox then you should be able to just `New` it up, no?

Comment: I am able to instantiate it with a "New" no problem.  The issue seems to be sticking it into MultiPage1.Pages(0).

Comment: `.Controls.Add(yourNewControl)`

Answer (score 0):

The identifier we need to use to add an ActiveX ListView dynamically is "MSComctlLib.ListViewCtrl" or "MSComctlLib.ListViewCtrl.2". This works:

```
Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.ListViewCtrl", "ListView1")
```

Here are some more identifiers in case you need to add other ActiveX controls dynamically:

```
MSComctlLib.ImageComboCtl.2
MSComctlLib.ImageListCtrl.2
MSComctlLib.ListViewCtrl.2
MSComctlLib.ProgCtrl.2
MSComctlLib.SBarCtrl.2
MSComctlLib.Slider.2
MSComctlLib.TabStrip.2
MSComctlLib.Toolbar.2
MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2
MSComCtl2.Animation.2
MSComCtl2.DTPicker.2
MSComCtl2.FlatScrollBar.2
MSComCtl2.MonthView.2
MSComCtl2.UpDown.2
```

And for good measure, here are the identifiers to use for the "normal" controls:

```
Forms.CheckBox.1
Forms.ComboBox.1
Forms.CommandButton.1
Forms.Frame.1
Forms.Image.1
Forms.Label.1
Forms.ListBox.1
Forms.MultiPage.1
Forms.OptionButton.1
Forms.ScrollBar.1
Forms.SpinButton.1
Forms.TabStrip.1
Forms.TextBox.1
Forms.ToggleButton.1
```

You might also be interested in reading about the special cases with regards to `MuliPage` and `TabStrip` in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/add-method-microsoft-forms).